# Stripe latest subscription Invoice

Tags: stripe-payments

I want to store every  invoice that a customer pays on a subscription. I wrote a database query to be executed when  "invoice.payment_succeeded" event is fired.  But what I did by mistake is that I took the latest invoice and stored its status in the Database:

```
$subscription_id = $response->data->object->subscription;
$subscription_obj = \Stripe\Subscription::retrieve($subscription_id);
$invoice_obj = \Stripe\Invoice::retrieve($subscription_obj->latest_invoice); 
$latest_invoice_status = $invoice_obj->status;
```

Instead of doing :

```
$invoice_obj = \Stripe\Invoice::retrieve($response->data->object->id);
```

Is there a problem in what I did or the latets invoice is just identical to the invoice captured in the event ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, this may not give some issue, unless you are allowing users some grace period post invoice not paid. And if this duration is long enough to generate a new invoice, you can get some issue tracking here.

This can be resolved if you keep the track of invoice and payments so late in any case if required you can analyse payments for the invoice.